# Show that $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{|ab|dx}{a^{2}\cos^{2}x + b^{2}\sin^{2}x} = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have tried out the tangent half angle substitution $\tan\frac{x}{2} = t$, which reduces the integrand to a rational expression. However, it appears to me that a more elegant solution is lurking round the corner. Any hints?

Comment: This integrand occurs here every now and then. Assuming $a$ and $b$ positive, you have a primitive function $\arctan(b/a\cdot \tan x)$, which one see if one factor $a^2\cos^2$ from the denominator. But I guess this should be closed as a duplicate in the end.

Comment: How about multiplying and dividing by $a\cos ^{2}x$ and the substituting for $\frac{b}{a} \tan x =t$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **NOTE $1$:**
>   For $a=b$, the result is trivial.  Therefore, we will assume $a\ne b$ herein.

---

> **NOTE $2$:**
>
> Although this integral can be easily evaluated since the integrand has a closed-form anti-derivative, I thought it would be instructive to apply the method of contour integration to see the application of a powerful analytical tool in action.
>
> ---

First we use (i) $\cos^2x=\frac12(1+\cos 2x)$, (ii) $\sin^2 x=\frac12(1-\cos 2x)$, and (iii) the evenness and $2\pi$-periodicity of the cosine, to write the integral of interest $I(a,b)$ as

$$\begin{align}
I(a,b)&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{|ab|}{a^2\cos^2x+b^2\sin^2x}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{|ab|}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)-(b^2-a^2)\cos x}\,dx
\end{align}$$

Moving to the complex plane, we let $z=e^{ix}$ so that $dz=\frac{1}{iz}\,dz$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
I(a,b)&=\frac{|ab|}{2}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{(a^2+b^2)+(a^2-b^2)\left(\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}\right)}\,\frac{1}{iz}dz\\\\
&=\frac{|ab|}{i(a^2-b^2)}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z^2+2\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2-b^2}z+1}\,dz\\\\
&=\frac{2\pi |ab|}{(a^2-b^2)}\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^2+2\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2-b^2}z+1}\right)\\\\
&=
\begin{cases}
\frac{2\pi |ab|}{(a^2-b^2)}\frac{1}{\frac{4|ab|}{|a^2-b^2|}}=\pi/2&,a>b\\\\
\frac{2\pi |ab|}{(a^2-b^2)}\frac{-1}{\frac{4|ab|}{|a^2-b^2|}}=\pi/2&,a<b
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Therefore, for all $a$ and $b$, we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{|ab|}{a^2\sin^2 x+b^2 \cos ^2 x}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

as was to be shown!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{|ab|dx}{a^{2}\cos^{2}x + b^{2}\sin^{2}x}&=|ab|\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sec^2x}{a^2+b^2 \tan^2 x}dx\\
& =|ab|\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac 1 {a^2+b^2\tan^2x}d(\tan x) \\
&= |ab| \left.\frac 1 {ab} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac {b\tan x}{a} \right)\right|_{x=0}^{\pi/2}\\
 &= \mp\frac{\pi}{2}\end{align}
After that what can you say about the minus ? Can you omit it??(Look at the integrand and conclude)

Comment: The $\mp$ just confuses. It should always be a $+$. If $ab>0$ then $b/a>0$ and the upper limit is arctan of something that tends to $+\infty$. If $ab<0$ then $b/a<0$ and you get the limit of arctan of something tending to $-\infty$. In any case you get $\pi/2$ and not $\mp\pi/2$. Also, there is an exceptional case $a=0$ and/or $b=0$.

Comment: No, think about $\frac{|ab|}{ab}$.. It is $\pm 1$.@mickep

Comment: If the integrand is positive then what can you say about the integral.??

Comment: Indeed $|ab|/(ab)$ is $\pm 1$, but $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\arctan(b/a\cdot\tan x)=\pm\pi/2$. Hence either both factors are positive (if $ab>0$) or they are negative (if $ab<0$). In the end, the result is $\pi/2$, not $\mp\pi/2$.

Comment: Isn't it simpler assuming that $a>0$ and $b>0$?